# Worksheet_Change is MUCH slower in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have this simple sub, which is located in a worksheet code:

```
Public current_plot As Integer
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then
        save_data (current_plot)
        restore_data (Target.Value)
        current_plot = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The range "plot" is of a single cell.

When I run this on Excel 2007 it takes a fraction of a second, while in Excel 2013 it takes about 10 seconds!

Here is what I know (in Excel 2013):

1. When I call `save_data` and `restore_data` from another sub, not in `Worksheet_Change` it works very fast.
2. When I call `Worksheet_Change` without calling `save_data` and `restore_data`, it also works fast (though, it does almost nothing...)
3. The computer running Excel 2013 has a significantly stronger hardware than the one with Excel 2007.
4. `save_data` and `restore_data` are fairly simple and should not take more than a second (and indeed it doesn't in Excel 2007).

I have searched the web and found others that complain about similar issues, and tried all the suggestions (mainly turning off the animation and other graphic accelerations) but nothing helps.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the events with Application.EnableEvents = False and then enabling it again before End Sub with Application.EnableEvents = True? Since you are changing the cell content inside the code, I suspect that change event is being triggered multiple times. Another way to check this is, insert a break point on the IF statement and manually debug the code with F8 to see if the change event code is being triggered more than once.

Comment: "save_data and restore_data are fairly simple and should not take more than a second" - well you would also have said that about the code you posted, and yet here we are (plus the previous three observations all point to the code you've *not* posted as likely being the issue)  Unless you've done some timings to show the slowness is only in the code you posted, you maybe haven't given us the whole story.

Comment: @TimWilliams, of course I timed the code! I tested these functions outside the `Worksheet_Change`, and they work very fast. Only when I call them from `Worksheet_Change` it becomes very slow. See bullet 1 above.

Comment: @sktneer Thanks! seems like you solve it. Though I don't understand why it's an issue only on Excel 2013, while in Excel 2007 it works smoothly.

Comment: That was kind of my point - I meant timings from within `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: @EBH well at least I can not digest that the same code takes different time in two versions. Create one workbook in 2007 itself and create another in 2013 itself and populate the same data in both of them. Now run the same code and evaluate the time taken by the code in two versions. As Tim said, it also depends upon what two other macros do. When a code runs, the time taken by the code may depend upon the data, formulas, conditional formatting etc etc. present in the workbook. So when you compare the code for speed in two workbooks of different versions, their structure must be the same.

Comment: @sktneer, I do the comparison on the exact same file. I just open it on different computers.